# Use external button for rich:fileUpload

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, web

I'm using the component rich:fileUpload for uploading files to my server the problem is that those files go along with a form that the user fills, so I wanna use one external button for doing this.

The user select the files to upload, fill the form and then click a "Submit" button at the bottom of the page. This upload the file with the form. I've tried it like this:

I'm able to hide the button inside the panel of fileUpload so the user don't click on it.

```
    <rich:fileUpload id="fileUploadId"
        style="width: 100%; height: 130px;"
        fileUploadListener="#{documentsBean.listener}"
        maxFilesQuantity="1"
        uploadButtonClass="display-none"
        uploadButtonClassDisabled="display-none">
    </rich:fileUpload>
```

And what I've tried with the button is

```
<a4j: commandButton  id="uploadFormButton"
        value="Attach"
        onclick="#{rich:component('fileUploadId')}.submitForm();"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('fileUploadId')}.clear(); return false;"/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do exactly what you want, but here is another solution you can use :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:st="http://spectotechnologies.com/jsf"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

    ...

    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ... your fields ...

        <t:inputFileUpload value="#{bean.document}" />

        <h:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{bean.onButtonSubmitClick}" />
    </h:form>
</html>
```

and the bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean
{
    private UploadedFile m_oDocument;

    public void setDocument(UploadedFile p_oDocument)
    {
        m_oDocument = p_oDocument;
    }

    @UploadedFileNotEmpty
    @UploadedFileSize(max="10000000")
    @UploadedFileExtension(accept="doc,docx,pdf,txt,rtf,xls,xlsx,zip,rar,jpg,jpeg,jpe,bmp,gif,png,csv,ppt,pptx,odp,pic,odt,ods")
    public UploadedFile getDocument()
    {
        return m_oDocument;
    }

    public void onButtonSubmitClick(ActionEvent p_oEvent)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!